# Access a variable from the main block in Progress 4GL

Tags: variables, scope, definition, openedge, progress-4gl

Is there a way to access a variable from the main block if I am in an internal procedure and the internal procedure defines a variable with the same name?

For example:

```
define variable myVariable as integer no-undo.

procedure myProcedure1:
  message "myProcedure1:" myVariable.
end.

procedure myProcedure2:
  define variable myVariable as integer no-undo.
  message "myProcedure2:" myVariable.
end.

myVariable = 123.

run myProcedure1.
run myProcedure2.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There us no way to do that while still defining a **variable** with the same name in the procedure.  However, you could redefine the variable as a parameter:

```
define variable myVariable as integer no-undo.

procedure myProcedure1:
  message "myProcedure1:" myVariable.
end.

procedure myProcedure2:
  define variable myVariable as integer no-undo.
  message "myProcedure2:" myVariable.
end.

procedure myProcedure3:
  define input parameter p1 as integer no-undo.
  define variable myVariable as integer no-undo.
  message "myProcedure3:" myVariable p1.
end.

procedure myProcedure4:
  define input parameter myVariable as integer no-undo.
  message "myProcedure4:" myVariable.
end.


myVariable = 123.

run myProcedure1.
run myProcedure2.
run myProcedure3 ( myVariable ).
run myProcedure4 ( myVariable ).
```